# JQuery hover toggle related selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a list of images and separate list where each item is related to an image. Is it possible to have a hover event that fades the related image in and out using JQuery? I.e. when you hover over listid-1, image-1 fades in.

This is the best I could do:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $( ".options li" ).hover(function( event ) {
    $('.image-' + (this - ".listid")).toggleFade( "300" );
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class='images'>
    <img class='image-1' src='1.jpg'>
    <img class='image-2' src='2.jpg'>
    <img class='image-3' src='3.jpg'>
    <img class='image-4' src='4.jpg'>
    <img class='image-5' src='5.jpg'>
  </div>
  <div class="options">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li class='listid-1'>One</li>
        <li class='listid-2'>Two</li>
        <li class='listid-3'>Three</li>
        <li class='listid-4'>Four</li>
        <li class='listid-5'>Five</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think the right function you were looking for is `.fadeToggle("300")` instead of `.toggleFade( "300" )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get class of current `li` and split at `-` to get number and use it as selector for image.

```js
$('img').hide()

$(".options li").hover(function() {
  $('.image-' + ($(this).attr('class').split('-')[1])).fadeToggle("300");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class='images'>
    <img class='image-1' src='1.jpg' alt="1">
    <img class='image-2' src='2.jpg' alt="2">
    <img class='image-3' src='3.jpg' alt="3">
    <img class='image-4' src='4.jpg' alt="4">
    <img class='image-5' src='5.jpg' alt="5">
  </div>
  <div class="options">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li class='listid-1'>One</li>
        <li class='listid-2'>Two</li>
        <li class='listid-3'>Three</li>
        <li class='listid-4'>Four</li>
        <li class='listid-5'>Five</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you have multiple classes on images instead you can use `data` attributes to select images.

```js
$('img').hide()

$(".options li").hover(function() {
  $('img.image-' + $(this).data('img')).fadeToggle(300)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class='images'>
    <img class='image-1' src='1.jpg' alt="1">
    <img class='image-2' src='2.jpg' alt="2">
    <img class='image-3' src='3.jpg' alt="3">
    <img class='image-4' src='4.jpg' alt="4">
    <img class='image-5' src='5.jpg' alt="5">
  </div>
  <div class="options">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li data-img="1" class='listid-1'>One</li>
        <li data-img="2" class='listid-2'>Two</li>
        <li data-img="3" class='listid-3'>Three</li>
        <li data-img="4" class='listid-4'>Four</li>
        <li data-img="5" class='listid-5'>Five</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Would this work if there were multiple classes, i.e. class='menu-item menu-item-34 listid-1' ?

Comment: No, i that case you can use custom data attributes.

Comment: How would I go about this?

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple of issues. Firstly concatenating the `this` reference with a string isn't going to give you a valid selector. Secondly, the method name is `fadeToggle()`, not `toggleFade()`.

To fix the problems you could first group the `li` and `img` elements by giving them all the same respective classes, then relate the hovered `li` to the `img` by their indexes, something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".options .listid").hover(function(event) {
    $('.image').eq($(this).index()).fadeToggle("300");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class='images'>
    <img class='image' src='1.jpg'>
    <img class='image' src='2.jpg'>
    <img class='image' src='3.jpg'>
    <img class='image' src='4.jpg'>
    <img class='image' src='5.jpg'>
  </div>
  <div class="options">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li class='listid'>One</li>
        <li class='listid'>Two</li>
        <li class='listid'>Three</li>
        <li class='listid'>Four</li>
        <li class='listid'>Five</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```